# Prepopulating Form with JSON post data?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, forms

I am currently working on a report system where a manager can create a report template dynamically, and then a user can submit that report.

The form builder is a simple jquery builder and the form template is saved as the following `[{"type":"text","label":"Report Raiser","req":1},{"type":"text","label":"Report Owner","req":1},{"type":"text","label":"Submission Date","req":1},{"type":"textarea","label":"Details","req":0}]`

And here is an example of a form post data saved

```
{"Report_Raiser":"amr","Report_Owner":"a","date":"2016-04-04","Details":"","Example_Form?":"a","Multi-Line_text_example":"","1_2_or_3?":["1","2","3"]}
```

I have been trying for a while now with no luck.
I am looking for a way to prepopulate a form so I can update the form.
If anyone can suggest a solution to this It would be a big help, bear in mind that the forms can change.

Answer (score -1):

When you first display your page, it should be already prepopulated. So it is about the server side application whatever you're using...
If you're not using any server side app, then hardcode the data into the form or find a source for the data and query it using jQuery AJAX.